# Почему не работает пример substr makefile

Tags: makefile

Я пытаюсь запустить под ubuntu пример makefile c функцией substr. Этот [пример](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_8.html)

```
comma:= ,
empty:=
space:= $(empty) $(empty)
foo:= a b c
bar:= $(subst $(space),$(comma),$(foo))
# bar is now `a,b,c'.
```

В своём makefile записал таким образом

```
all:
    comma:= ,
    empty:=
    space:= $(empty) $(empty)
    foo:= a b c
    bar:= $(subst $(space),$(comma),$(foo))
    # bar is now `a,b,c'.
```

При запуске выходит такая ошибка:

```
elvin@ubuntu:~$ make all
comma:= ,
/bin/sh: 1: comma:=: not found
makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Что я делаю не так в этом примере и как избавиться от этой ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определения макросов находятся вне рецептов.

```
comma := ,
empty :=
space := $(empty) $(empty)
foo := a b c
bar := $(subst $(space),$(comma),$(foo))

all:
    echo $(bar)
```